# Convert dataframe to dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I intend to get a dictionary with column name as key from a dataframe.

Suppose I have a dataframe:

```
    a    b
 0  ac   dc
 1  ddd  fdf
```

I want the output as:

```
{a : ac, b : dc}
```

I want it to be done row by row. Any sort of help would be greatly appreciated.
Here I want the column name as the key in the resulting dictionary.

Comment: Maybe `df.to_dict(orient='list')`

Comment: @Altoyr Here I want to take the column name as the key.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`to_dict()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) method with `orient='records'`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{'a': 'ac', 'b': 'dc'}, {'a': 'ddd', 'b': 'fdf'}])
print(df)

#      a    b
# 0   ac   dc
# 1  ddd  fdf

d = df.to_dict(orient='records')
print(d)

# [{'b': 'dc', 'a': 'ac'}, {'b': 'fdf', 'a': 'ddd'}]
```